# "Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection" during send mail using grails async mail api

Tags: grails, asynchronous

I am trying to send mail using [Grails Async Mail API](http://grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail)

When I tried for Gmail using below configuration :

```
grails {
   mail {
      host = "smtp.gmail.com"
      port = 465
      username = "xxxx@gmail.com"
      password = "xxxx"
      props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",                        
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
               "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
   }
}
```

in **config.groovy**, I was able to send mail. When I changed above configuration for a specific mail server as below :

```
grails {
  mail {
    host = "xxx"
    port = 25
    username = "xxx"
    props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"false",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"25",                           
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"true",
             "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": "false",
             "mail.smtp.starttls.required": "false"]
  }
}
```

I am getting below error :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: xxx, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
```

Please provide me some hint, what I am doing wrong in above case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do simply following and it should work for you

```
grails {
  mail {
    host = "xxx"
    port = 25
    username = "xxx"
    props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"false",
             "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"25",                           
             "mail.smtp.starttls.enable": "true"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Trying to configure grails mail plugin in a grails 2.3 app to work with mailtrap.io, this recommendation works for me, thanks